# weird EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, exc-bad-access

I have a for loop in my Objective-C code that keeps throwing a **`EXC_BAD_ACCESS`** error. Here is the code:

```
double (*X)[2];

for (int bufferCount=0; bufferCount < audioBufferList.mNumberBuffers; bufferCount++) {
    SInt16* samples = (SInt16 *)audioBufferList.mBuffers[bufferCount].mData;
    for (int i=0; i < 1024; i+=2){//numSamplesInBuffer / 2; i+=2) {
        X[i][0] = samples[i];
        X[i][1] = samples[i + 1];

        NSLog(@"left: %f", X[i][0]);
        NSLog(@"right: %f", X[i][1]);
        NSLog(@"i: %d", i);
    }
}
```

When `i = 385`, I get a **`EXC_BAD_ACCESS`** at the line `NSLog(@"left: %f:", X[i][0]);`.

Thinking it may be a memory issue with **X** being declared locally, I changed **X** to a property which caused a **`EXC_BAD_ACCESS`** at the first line of the for loop on the first time through.

Anyone know why this may be happening?

Comment: My guess is that `X` isn't what you think it is.  How is it being allocated?

Comment: (In fact, looking at your code again, I *know* that X isn't what you think it is.)

Comment: Admittedly I'm not fabulous at C, but I need a 2-dim array, so I am using a pointer to create that.

Comment: Coder, where do you actually allocate the array??

Comment: @JasonCoco I had tried that previously as well, and I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the first line in the for loop

Comment: @HotLicks You were right I wasn't allocating space for the array.

Comment: @HotLicks If you want to put it in an answer, I can accept it...

Comment: @coder Even if your allocate space, your loop is also wrong as half the space will be wasted since you'll only be storing in every other element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As HotLicks pointed out, the problem was that I wasn't allocating any space for the array. The solution was to initialize the array like this:

```
double (*X)[2] = malloc(2 * 1024 * sizeof(double));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
double X[512][2];

for (int bufferCount=0; bufferCount < audioBufferList.mNumberBuffers; bufferCount++) {
    SInt16* samples = (SInt16 *)audioBufferList.mBuffers[bufferCount].mData;
    for (int i=0; i < 512; i++) {
        int sample_offset = i * 2;
        X[i][0] = samples[sample_offset];
        X[i][1] = samples[sample_offset + 1];

        NSLog(@"left: %f", X[i][0]);
        NSLog(@"right: %f", X[i][1]);
        NSLog(@"i: %d", i);
    }
}
```